# How to change the color of a pixel to the average color of the pixels surrounding it?

Tags: python, colors, average, pixel

I am trying to change the color of the pixels at (0, 12, 24, 34, 44, ...). I want to make their color the average of the color of the 4 pixels surrounding each pixel.

I tried this:

```
import skimage.io as io

image= io.imread("image.png")

w=image.shape[0]
h=image.shape[1]

i = range (0, (w*h), 11) 

count = 0
for row in range(w):
    for col in range(h):
        if count in i:
            image[row][col]=(((image[row+1][col])+(image[row+1][col])+(image[row][col+1])+(image[row][col-1]))/4)
        count += 1
        
io.imshow(hiddenImage)
io.show()
```

It shows me this error: IndexError: index 2016 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2016
How can I fix this?

NOTE: The image shape is (1512, 2016, 3)

Comment: i = range (0, (w*h), 11) doesn't produce `(0, 12, 24, 34, 44, ...)` it produces `(0, 11, 22, 33, 44,..)`.

Comment: But even when I change the steps of the range to 12, I get an out of range error. IndexError: index 1512 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1512

Comment: Because though your `row < w` and `col < h`, but `row + 1` might be equal to `w(=1512)` which is not a valid index and same for `col+1`.